# app crashes after recording

Tags: android, audio, wav

```
mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();
Thread auto_stop=new Thread(new Runnable()
{

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        if(WavAudioRecorder.flag)
        {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.reset();
            btnControl.setText("Start");
            return ;

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

});
auto_stop.start();
```

I am trying to make a recorder app which records for 30 secs and gets stopped.I am using the above mentioned code for stopping the recorder.The app crashes after recording for 30 seconds.How can the crashing part be resolved?
The code which i am using for starting and stoppin is in this [link](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/tree/master/AndroidWaveRecorder).
Is there any other way to stop the recorder automatically after 30 secs

```
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6313)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3567)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at com.example.androidwaverecorder.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:53)
04-23 09:53:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: You can use handlers...

Comment: I am just a beginner so please can you tell me in detail

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: Use [`mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxDuration(int)) for setting max record duration

Comment: I am using audioRecord class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `btnControl.setText("Start");` from another thread. I recommend you use [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for asynchronous work (like your recording) and display data in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods.

Comment: can u just explain what is preExecute and postExecute